# How to get Category Id from Post Id ?

Tags: posts, categories

I need to get any post category id from the post id(Not for current) Post.
How can i ?

Thanks

Comment: i used this code . but i got i array is blank global $post;
$category_detail=get_the_category( $post->ID );

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this code for getting category id from post id:

```
global $post;
$category_detail=get_the_category( $post->ID );
```

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [wp_get_post_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_categories) function. It returns an array of categories' ID for specific post.

```
$post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id );
```